# Mysql Percona backup is shutting down the mysql instance

Tags: mysql, percona

I am running a basic back of my mysql database. I am unsure why it's shutting down.  I am getting the backup completed message and I am getting completed after the prepare.  But the instance still crashes.  I am running two instances only I am backing up one.

```
xtrabackup --defaults-file=/etc/alternatives/my.cnf --defaults-group=mysqld5 --socket=/var/run/mysqld/db5.sock --user=mysqladmin --password=password --backup --throttle 400 --target-dir=/mysqlbackup/current --no-timestamp 2> /var/backup.log;
```

I cat the log file to make sure it completed and it does complete. I then run prepare

```
xtrabackup --prepare --use-memory=5G --target-dir=/mysqlbackup/current 2 >> /var/backup.log;
```

My log file has

```
xtrabackup: cd to /mysqlbackup/current
xtrabackup: This target seems to be not prepared yet.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 5642017177088 (8%)
Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 5642076559654 (99%)
Database was not shutdown normally
Starting crash recovery
Progress in percent: 0 1 2 ... 99
Apply batch completed
InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 1 redo rollback segment(s) are active.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 748935ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
InnoDB: 5.7.26 started; log sequence number 5642076559654 
xtrabackup: Last MySQL binlog file position 7017599, file name binlog.000009
xtrabackup: Recovered WSREP position: febfad99-09fe-11ea-ad83-57c73422d738:27384750                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
xtrabackup: starting shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
InnoDB: Starting shutdown...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 5642076561674                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
InnoDB: Number of pools: 1                                      
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_home_dir = . 
InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=5642076561674
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 5642076561941 (0%) 
InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally! 
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery
InnoDB: Starting shutdown...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 5642076561960                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
200213 08:05:36 completed OK!
```

Comment: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/how_xtrabackup_works.html "It copies your InnoDB data files, which results in data that is internally inconsistent; but then it performs crash recovery on the files to make them a consistent, usable database again."

Comment: After the end of crash recovery the database should be ready for connections.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-recovery.html#innodb-crash-recovery

Comment: Is your database actually not ready for connections after a backup? Like, you're having to manually start it back up again? If so, how much RAM does your server have?

Comment: Yes I have to manually start mysql.  I have 120 ish gig of ram

Answer (score 1):

Connect to your running MySQL Server, and run this in the client:

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| Uptime        | 268121 |
+---------------+--------+
```

The value is the number of seconds since your MySQL Server last started (the example I show above is from mysql on my own laptop, and works out to 74 hours, which is the last time I rebooted).

I think you'll find your value of uptime indicates your MySQL Server has been running fine through the time of your backup.

Percona XtraBackup does not restart your MySQL Server. It restarts its own InnoDB engine, to simulate crash recovery against the files it just backed up.

XtraBackup uses a lot of code that is borrowed from the InnoDB engine in MySQL itself, so it maintains compatibility with the format of InnoDB files. It uses the crash-recovery feature of InnoDB to "prepare" its copies of InnoDB files, to resolve any unfinished transactions.

By borrowing the code from the InnoDB engine, it outputs similar messages.

Comment: I have to manually restart the mysql instance after the backup and prepare job is done.  So the server is down. Checking the time give me `19576` which is about `5 hours`

Comment: That's not normal experience for XtraBackup. At my job, we use XtraBackup on thousands of MySQL instances every night, and it does not cause them to go down. My guess is that when you do `--use-memory=5G` it is too much, and causing the mysqld process to crash due to exhausted system memory.

Comment: I just recently added `--use-memory=5G` to maybe stop the crashing.  The network admin said oom killer is being fired and that is killing mysql

Comment: Use `ps` or `top` to figure out how much memory your mysqld process is using, and use `free` or `top` to figure out how much memory you have available. It's up to you to manage the memory usage so it doesn't exceed the physical memory on your server.

Comment: "The network admin said oom killer is being fired and that is killing mysql" This would be great info to have included in your question... and it seems to answer it.

Comment: That is the weird thing memory isnt spiking.  Checked my stats and I have like 10G of memory free

Comment: The spike in memory use might be brief. Check this answer, it might give you a method of checking the max memory usage on the system: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264368/does-linux-maintain-a-system-ram-high-water-mark